# Ajax request causes page refresh when sending files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I don't have much experience with ajax but seeing an issue when sending form data to a ASP controller.

#### Scenario 1

Set `data` in ajax request to

```
$(this).serialize()
```

All form data is posted to the conrtroller without any page redirect, but excludes any files sent with the form.

#### Scenario 2

set `data` in ajax request to

```
formdata
```

All form data is posted, including uploaded files, but the page refreshes, which I do not want to happen.

What is going on here, and how can I send the files without refreshing the page?

#### Code

```
// Clear any previous 'success' messages (in case of error)
$('form .btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#result').html('');
});
// Submit form
$('form').submit(function () {
    // Build form data
    var formdata = new FormData(); 
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
    }
    // Send ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: formdata, // fails to send files when set to $(this).serialize()
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('form .btn').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('form .btn').prop('disabled', false)
            $('form .form-control').val('');
            $('#result').html('Thank you. We will contact you shortly.');
            $('.validation-summary-errors ul li').css('display', 'none');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            $('form .btn').prop('disabled', false)
            alert('An error occurred on the server. Please try again. \n\n If this keep happening, please email us at office@auroraglobal.ru');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Forms are tasked with sending the information (even if there is not a destination to go to) and refresh the page. you need to set an `event.preventDefault();` on your form to prevent this from happening when it submits. I think you would do it like `$(form).submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ...rest of your logic}` https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: @BrandonBenefield Thanks for your comment. I added `preventDefault` but also had to add a few other options (`contetType`, `processData`), now getting a missing antiforgery error, will have to investigate that

Answer (score 0):

eventMaking minor changes to your code, you should have this:

```
// Clear any previous 'success' messages (in case of error)
$('form .btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#result').html('');
});
// Submit form
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this prevents the page from refreshing

    // Build form data
    var formdata = new FormData(); 
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
    }
    // Send ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: formdata, // fails to send files when set to $(this).serialize()
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('form .btn').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('form .btn').prop('disabled', false)
            $('form .form-control').val('');
            $('#result').html('Thank you. We will contact you shortly.');
            $('.validation-summary-errors ul li').css('display', 'none');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            $('form .btn').prop('disabled', false)
            alert('An error occurred on the server. Please try again. \n\n If this keep happening, please email us at office@auroraglobal.ru');
        }
    });
});
```